# Expression of $E[(X-a)^3]$ as a function of $\operatorname{Var}(X)$ and/or $\sigma_x$

Tags: probability, variance, expected-value, standard-deviation

Just a question:

I would be able to express $\mathrm{E}\left[(X-a)^{3}\right]$ as a function of $\sigma_x$
and/or $\sigma_x^2$, with $a$ a constant (surely $\mathrm{E}\left[X\right]$ terms should appear).

Even an approximation would be sufficient (I think potentialy to a Taylor expansion but I can't conclude currently with this).

I have no informations about the distribution of random variable $X$ : the only things I know are $\sigma_x$ and $\mu_x$ : it is difficult to characterize $X$ since these numerical values are provided from a complex code

**EDIT :** The notion of skewness could help maybe. Here's the definition :

**Notes :**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The sample skewness is computed as the Fisher-Pearson coefficient of skewness, i.e.
$$
g_{1}=\frac{m_{3}}{m_{2}^{3 / 2}}
$$
where
$$
m_{i}=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N}(x[n]-\bar{x})^{i}
$$
is the biased sample $i$ th central moment, and $\bar{x}$ is the sample mean. If bias is False, the calculations are corrected for bias and the value computed is the adjusted Fisher-Pearson standardized moment coefficient, i.e.
$$
G_{1}=\frac{k_{3}}{k_{2}^{3 / 2}}=\frac{\sqrt{N(N-1)}}{N-2} \frac{m_{3}}{m_{2}^{3 / 2}}
$$

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am in a special case where I know only the $2$ central moment $m_{2}$ for 5 bins and not directly the data $x[n]$.

Could I apply this method to data $\sigma_i$ (there is in total 5 elements from a 5x1 vector) ?

But if I could, how to exploit this to combine with it to compute `the Fisher-Pearson coefficient of skewness` ?

Comment: Expand the cube inside. Use the formula linking variance to second moment and first moment squared to replace any squared term and make variance appear.

Comment: Also, look up definition of skewness

Comment: @ThreeDiag . Thanks for your quick answer. Could you write please the trick? , I didn't understand all your reasoning. Regards

Comment: @fblundun All I can say is that $a$ is comprised between he value 1 and 2 : "$1 < a < 2$ : could you think an approximation is possible is this case ?

Comment: @ThreeDiag. Thanks for your relevant answer : could you take a look please at my **EDIT** ? Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will show by example three density function all with zero mean, variance one, but different third moments (skew). As example I will use the standard normal distribution, and two [skew-normal distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution) with $\alpha$ parameter $\pm 3$:

[image: three density functions]

Since these three distributions have the same first two moments, but different third moment, the answer should be clear.

Answer (score 2):

$$E[(X-a)^3] =E[X^3 - 3X^2a+3Xa^2-a^3] = E[X^3] - 3aE[X^2]+3a^2E[X]-a^3$$

$$E[X^2]=\sigma_X^2+\mu_X^2$$

$$E[(X-a)^3] = E[X^3] - 3a(\sigma_X^2+\mu_X^2)+3a^2\mu_X-a^3$$

Only with $E[X^3]$ you can retrieve an exact result.
Without further information on $X$ it is not possible to say anything else on $E[X^3]$.

Comment: This is not a logical demonstration of your conclusion.  To show that it is impossible to recover $E[(X-a)^3]$ from lower moments, you need to exhibit variables that have the same lower moments but dramatically different values of $E[(X-a)^3].$ Ideally, you would also demonstrate that the range of mathematically possible values of $E[(X-a)^3]$ is not restricted based on information about those lower moments.

Comment: Just try a normal and skew-normal with mean 0 and the same variance ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen . Fine for your suggestion. Could you take a look please at my EDIT ? I think I could maybe compute $E[(X-\mu)^3]$ by using skewness coefficient but I don't know yet how to implement it in my code knowing I just have $\sigma_i$ and $\mu_i$ for each bin (5 values in total) ? Regards